# pyspark - how to add express in withColumn

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I wanted to add a new column which is conctenation of two existing columns and I am using the following query : What is the issue with this query ? I am seeing "null" for new columns

```
df.select(df['DEST_COUNTRY_NAME'],df['ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME']).withColumn("COMPLETE_PATH",df['DEST_COUNTRY_NAME'] + ",").filter(df['DEST_COUNTRY_NAME']=='Egypt').show()

+-----------------+-------------------+-------------+
|DEST_COUNTRY_NAME|ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME|COMPLETE_PATH|
+-----------------+-------------------+-------------+
|            Egypt|      United States|         null|
|            Egypt|      United States|         null|
|            Egypt|      United States|         null|
|            Egypt|      United States|         null|
|            Egypt|      United States|         null|
|            Egypt|      United States|         null|
+-----------------+-------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.4/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.concat

Comment: Any reason why these functions _need_ to be used than regular python functions ?

Comment: yes. you are working with a spark dataframe, not a pandas dataframe. therefore, your dataframe is handled by spark wich use scala language which use JVM ... so, if you want to use python simple functions/syntax, you need to create an UDF.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.concat
...
df.withColumn(concat(col("DEST_COUNTRY_NAME"), lit(",")))
```